# Nbitcoin's BitcoinPubKeyAddress not recognizing native segwit addresses

Tags: address, segregated-witness, c#, nbitcoin

I'm trying to build a transaction using Nbitcoin. When I run this line there is an error parsing the address. It runs fine with segwit addresses starting with a 1, but not native segwit.

```
Using System;
Using System.Text;
Using NBitcoin;

static void Main(string[] args) {

    var wallet = new BitcoinPubKeyAddress("bc1q....", Network.Main); //throws error
}
```

**Error:** System.FormatException: 'Invalid base58 data'

Is there a way to use native segwit with Nbitcoin? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

> It runs fine with segwit addresses starting with a 1, but not native segwit.

Prefix `1` is used by legacy addresses. You can check the other prefixes used here: https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/List_of_address_prefixes

> Is there a way to use native segwit with Nbitcoin?

Replace `BitcoinPubKeyAddress` with `BitcoinWitPubKeyAddress` in your code for using native segwit addresses